# Finding the outlier in array?

Tags: c#, arrays

---

Hi, this may be an obvious or simple fix but I personally cannot find any problem with this program to cause 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException : Index was outside the bounds of the array.' For the small arrays I've tested it works fine but apparently on some tests it gives that error (Doesn't show the array input for the error ones). Any ideas? I'm still new so don't mind me heh.

```
    {

        int[] numbers = new int[] { 17, 17, 3, 17, 17, 17, 17 };
        int outlier = 0;

        Array.Sort(numbers);
        if (numbers[0] == numbers[1])
        {
            if (numbers[numbers.Length] == numbers[numbers.Length - 1])
            {
                outlier = numbers[numbers.Length];
            }
        } else { outlier = numbers[0]; }

        Console.WriteLine(outlier);
    }
```

Comment: c# arrays are zero-based ... also I suggest you check out inter-quartile range and outliers

Comment: One of the most important things to learn if you're new is [how to use a debugger](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/).

Answer (score 1):

Your array length (numbers.Length) is 7 and you are trying to get numbers[7].
Array index start from position 0. So you will get upto array[6].
For clearence:

```
numbers[0]=17;
numbers[1]=17;
numbers[2]=3;
numbers[3]=17;
numbers[4]=17;
numbers[5]=3;
numbers[6]=17;
numbers[numbers.length]=number[7]=?
```

This is where you are getting System.IndexOutOfRangeException : Index was outside the bounds of the array.
Try number[numbers.length-1].

Answer (score 0):

```
numbers[numbers.Length]
```

The length of an array with one element inside it is one. But that single element will be at position 0.
You're trying to access...LET'S SAY... element 0 a.k.a.

```
numbers[0]
```

via

```
numbers[1]
```

which is out of bounds, since there is only one element inside the array, which is at index = 0.

Answer (score 0):

Look at https://dotnetfiddle.net/WdWCjM   I showed you the sample arrays and outcomes. simply uncomment lines to see the outcomes.

```
//    int[] numbers = new int[] { 17, 17, 3, 17, 17, 17, 17 };  //3  is the outlier

// empty array will always fail when you are looking for numbers[0].
 //  int[] numbers = new int[] {  }; //Run-time exception (line 12): Index was outside     
   the bounds of the array.

//array with only one member will always fail when looking for  numbers[1]-- the 
   second element.
//   int[] numbers = new int[] { 17 }; //Run-time exception (line 13): Index was 
   outside the bounds of the array.

//outlier = numbers[numbers.Length]  
// an array of lenth = 2  will have numbers[0] and numbers[1]. Your code shows number[2], which will always fail.
//   int[] numbers = new int[] { 17, 17 };// Run-time exception (line 16): Index was 
  outside the bounds of the array.

// this only workes because you sort the array. making 3 the first element (numbers[0]) which matches the element.length(number of elements in array);
//  int[] numbers = new int[] { 17, 17, 3}; //3
```

here is a solution, assuming you want the number with least occurences in an array
https://dotnetfiddle.net/8ymzoM